# What are implementation and production mean in TDD

Tags: tdd

My question is all in the title. Whenever I search or study TDD, I encounter those words, **implementation** and **production**. But I don't know the exact mean, just have assumptions. What are the notions of implementation and production?

For example, in this [article](https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da)'s **Fake** part, he or she said

**Fakes are objects that have working implementations, but not same as production one. Usually they take some shortcut and have simplified version of production code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fakes are objects that have working implementations, but not same as production one.

When you write test you need to simulate the behavior of some classes (DAO, repository...), you will write a new implementation of the Class which will differ from your production code.

```
// your production code  
class UserRepository {
    public function find(Integer id){
         // get a record from the database
         return new User(...); // populate the user from the record
    }
}

//your fake implementation for make your test passed
class FakeUserRepository {
    public function find(Integer id){
         return new User('firstname', 'lastname');
    }
}
```